# Single Line in same place on different models

Tags: creality-ender-3

I just got an Ender 3 S1 Pro and I've done a few prints using fairly stock settings out of Cura. A few minor tweaks to Layer Height and Start temps. I've done some research but can't really find an example of this issue. If someone can give me some insight, that would be very helpful.

[image: Photo of a 3D printed rabbit model with a printing error partway up the model]

[image: Photo of a calibration cube with a printing error partway up the model]

Comment: Have you checked the z-axis screw for a bad spot.

Answer (score 2):

If this defect is present in all your printed models, there most likely is something wrong with the mechanics of the printer. Check the rollers, the vertical posts and the screw. Make sure sure everything runs smoothly. Also look out for hitting external object near the printer like e.g. spool holders.

Comment: As suggested, check the components that move. One could have a tiny bit of debris in a roller/wheel, but the flaw in the model would be more periodic.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, every print has had the same defect.
What solved it for me was calibration. I calibrated the printer once, it was already better, then I calibrated it another time and it was gone.

Comment: Hi Anouvee, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Unfortunately your answer is marked with a low quality score by the system. Please expand your answer explaining what you mean by calibration by [edit]. Please explain in detail how calibration effects on the defect (the line present in the prints). Thanks!